# Upgrading a Joomla! 2.5 component to Joomla! 3 - JToolbar in Administrator doesn't work

Tags: component, custom-component, migration

I am attempting to upgrade an old (custom) component for Joomla! 2.5 to 3.0, and I've been having issues with a few things, mainly JToolbar.

When I click on any button, I get this in my error console:

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n.task') (submitform — core.js:1:213)`

If I just press return/enter in the form, it refreshes the page and doesn't save any information. I already went through and renamed JElement to JFormField, replaced var properties with `public $type`, and switched all JController/Model/etc. to their Legacy versions.

I tried looking around for articles, lists, and tutorials but I couldn't find anything at all about migrating actual components from 2.5 to 3 other than a small list of incompatibilities and a brief mention of `J*Legacy` classes and the changes that I mentioned. Everything else that comes up is all about just migrating actual installations from 2.5 to 3.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that all of the administrator forms needed to have `id="adminForm"` on them. The project that I was working on did not.

Answer (score 1):

A prominent cause of this issue is browser caching. Delete your browser cache and see if that fixes the problem. This will ensure that you will be using the latest JS libraries.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that a lot of the forms in the project did not have `id="adminForm"`. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Even though this wasn't the answer in this case, it is a solution in a high number instances where the admin interface stops responding after the update to 3.5.1.